# Output 3D points change everytime in triangulatePoints using in Python 2.7 with OpenCV 3.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, stereo-3d

I want to know 3D points from stereo cameras using `triangulatePoints` in Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.3. For that, I calibrated stereo cameras and stored matrices in the folder. I also rectified my images using `cv2.stereoRectify` and by using  `cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap` undistort the images. Then I saved those images as well as projection matrices P1 and P2 and find the corresponding point in both images. Point in left image `ptl = np.array([304,277])` and corresponding point in right image `ptr = np.array([255,277])`. After that I tried `points = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1,P2,ptl,ptr)`. Code is:

```
    import cv2
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        cameraMatrixL = np.load('mtx_left.npy')
        distCoeffsL = np.load('dist_left.npy')
        cameraMatrixR = np.load('mtx_right.npy')
        distCoeffsR = np.load('dist_right.npy')
        R = np.load('R.npy')
        T = np.load('T.npy')
    # following matrices I saved which i got from stereoRectify
        R1 = np.load('R1.npy')
        R2 = np.load('R2.npy')
        P1 = np.load('P1.npy')
        P2 = np.load('P2.npy')
        Q = np.load('Q.npy')
# upload alreday distorted and rectified images
        imgL = cv2.imread('D:\python/triangulate in 3 D\left.png',0)
        imgR = cv2.imread('D:\python/triangulate in 3 D/right.png',0)
        ptl = np.array([304,277]) # point in left image
        ptr = np.array([255,277]) # Corresponding point in right image
        points = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1,P2,ptl,ptr)
        print points
```

But when ever I run this code my results got changed (also all results are wrong). One time results look like

```
[[  518845863]
 [ 1667138857]
 [-1189385102]
 [    -661713]]
```

Another time results look like

```
[[-1766436066]
 [          0]
 [          0]
 [-1299735447]]
```

Sometimes it looks like

```
[[        0]
 [        0]
 [697559541]
 [        0]]
```

I don't know why the results are changing even my all parameters are same only? Also, these 3D points are incorrect. How to correct these problems?

**Edit:** *I observed one thing in this code, after running that it not get completed. It neither shows `Process finished with exit code 0` nor `Process finished with exit code 1`. when I pressed red stop button it finished with `Process finished with exit code 1`. Why so? I think due to this only above error is coming. Why this code not running with `Process finished with exit code 0`?*

Comment: Are you sure the images are being loaded? normally in python (and a lot of other languages) the \ is a escape character, so it takes \p like some special character... it should be \\, also do not mix / with \ in the addresses

Comment: Thanks, @api55 Sir, I just solved this problem. But I am getting error in output points. Would you suggest me something about this, how to reduce error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, after so many tries I found out what mistake I was doing. Actually, I was defining my points in code in the wrong way. According to [triangulatePoints document](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints), points should be

> projPoints1 – 2xN array of feature points in the first image.

But in code I wrote

```
ptl = np.array([304,277]) # point in left image
ptr = np.array([255,277]) # Corresponding point in right image
```

means I was defining `1x2` array while I should define `2x1` array for single point. likewise for 5 points array should be `2x5`. For `N` points offcourse `2xN`. Initially, I didn't notice this because I used to do traingulation in Matlab and there corresponding points are used as Nx2 array.Now I put my points like

```
l = np.array([[ 304],[ 277]],dtype=np.float)
r = np.array([[ 255 ],[ 277]],dtype=np.float)
```

and I got above code working.

One more point `dtype=np.float` is important in defining this point array to avoid wrong results.

Results what I got is not very accurate and shows error of nearly 20-25 mm but I solved above problem so I answer this question and now I have to find out the way to minimise errors. If anybody knows how to reduce error please tell me.